# Detect if wired connection is active

Tags: connection, ubuntu-mate

I use my sleep button a lot and would like to have a sound file played when my wired connection is re-established so I know I can use my browser.

Is that possible?

Comment: Not while you're in SUSPEND/HIBERNATE, assuming that's what "use my sleep button " means

Comment: @waltinator I guess OP means when the computer comes out of suspend or hybernate, he would like a sound when the computer reconnects using the Ethernet.

Comment: I do something like this with https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic "Monitor for link  down, do a user-specified thing to fix it". After that, it's a SMOP (Simple Matter Of Programming).